# Passing parameters to form action in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms, django-urls

Template:

```
<form method="post" action="/reply/{{feed.id}}/">

    {{rform.as_p}}

    <input type="submit" value="send" /> 

</form>
```

and url:

```
(r'^reply/(\d+)/$',reply),
```

But when we submit the form, `{{feed.id}}` is not translated and url directs to `/reply//`

Are parameters not allowed in form actions?
If its allowed then why is it not working here?

Thanks

Comment: If it directs to `/reply//` (with double slashes), `{{feed.id}}` outputs empty string. It's the problem.

Comment: Please give more context - no idea of where `feed` comes from

Answer (score 1):

If `{{ feed.id }}` is empty it means that that either `feed.id` is empty, or `feed` is None.  Make sure you are passing `feed` in your view context when you render the template using `render_to_response`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your feed is dictionary object?

In your `views.py` module

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response;

def myforms(request):
    feed = {"id":"369"}
    return render_to_response('html-template/blank.html', {'feed': feed})
```